# Aviso: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Tags: php, array, api, variáveis, magento

Bom dia pessoal, estou criando sitema para atualizar o estoque do magento através de uma API, para isso usei um módulo para facilitar o processo, tambem estou consumundo uma api via curl com PHP, o meu erro estavá na variável indefinida, porem usei o métado das variaves globais para resolver e agora esta dando erro no array_search()

```
class InventoryUpdate
{
    

    /** @var Iterator  */
    private $iterator;

    /** @var StockRegistryInterface  */
    private $stockRegistry;

    /** @var ProductCollectionFactory  */
    private $productCollection;

    /** @var LoggerInterface  */
    private $logger;


    /**
     * InventoryUpdate constructor.
     *
     * @param StockRegistryInterface   $stockRegistry
     * @param Iterator                 $iterator
     * @param ProductCollectionFactory $productCollection
     * @param LoggerInterface          $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        Iterator $iterator,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollection,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->iterator = $iterator;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       
        $productCollection = $this->productCollection->create();
        $this->iterator ->walk($productCollection->getSelect(), [[$this,'updateItems']]);
    }

    public function api() {

        $headers = [
                'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb2RfZmlsaWFsIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlIjpbImRyb2dhcmlhIl0sInRva2VuX2ludGVncmFjYW8iOiJ0cnVlIiwiY29kX2Zhcm1hY2lhIjoiMTA2MTEiLCJleHAiOjQxMDI0NTU2MDAsImlhdCI6MTY0MTQ4NzM0NywianRpIjoiMmM1ZmNlYWQtYjJhOC00OTVhLWIxZGEtMjU4YWU0OTBiNzZhIiwiY29kX3VzdWFyaW8iOiIxMDkiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJBUElfSU5URUdSQUNBTyJdfQ.niU8xVYgvfJThel_Kmk4tBEDTvTprU3sIfgGvLhMDyw'
            ];

            //INICIA O CURL
            $curl = curl_init();

            //CONFIGURAÇOES DO CURL
            curl_setopt_array($curl,[
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://homologacao.triersistemas.com.br/sgfpod1/rest/integracao/estoque/obter-todos-v1?primeiroRegistro=0&quantidadeRegistros=10",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            ]);

            //RESPONSE
            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            //FECHA A CONEXÃO ABERTA
            curl_close($curl);

            $array = json_decode($response);

            $qtdEstoque = array_column($array, 'quantidadeEstoque');
            $cdgProduto = array_column($array,  'codigoProduto');    
    }
        
    public function updateItems($args)
    {

        global $array;
        global $cdgProduto;
        global $qtdEstoque;
        
        $sku = $args['row']['sku'];
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
        $currentQty = $stockItem->getQty(); //qtd atual no estoque (você pode pular a atualização caso a quantidade não tenha sido alterada)

        //$GLOBALS['cdgProduto']
        echo $sku;
        echo "\n";


        $id = array_search($sku,  $GLOBALS['cdgProduto']);

       
    }
}
```

Criei a função com o nome "api()" para consumir a api nisso deu erro de variável indefinida, usei `$GLOBALS['cdgProduto']` para ficar visto de outra função deu certo, porem deu erro no array_search()

#### Como eu posso resolver esse erro ?? tendo em mente que não posso colocar tudo na função `updateItems()` pois ela fica em loop infinito por causa do iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, o erro está explicito, de alguma forma `$GLOBALS['cdgProduto']` está vindo como null.

Você precisa tratar este caso, e caso ele for esperado, você pode fazer um null-check antes de passar para a busca (`array_search`)

O `isset` funciona bem para este caso. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```php
if (isset($GLOBALS['cdgProduto']) {
    $id = array_search($sku,  $GLOBALS['cdgProduto']);
}
```

Verifique seu fluxo se realmente `$GLOBALS['cdgProduto']` pode ser null ou não.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo eu usei oque tu falou e variável normal  $cdgProduto